# using column numbers for grouping in data table rather than names in R

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, grouping

I have code that needs to be flexible, and I cannot hard code in column names when I do grouping.  As such, I want to hard code column numbers to do grouping, since these are easy to specify over range changes.  (Column 1 through X or so, rather than using the names of cols 1,2,..X)

Example data set:

```
set.seed(007) 
DF <- data.frame(X=1:20, Y=sample(c(0,1), 20, TRUE), Z=sample(0:5, 20, TRUE), Q =sample(0:5, 20, TRUE))



 DF
    X Y Z Q
1   1 1 3 4
2   2 0 1 2
3   3 0 5 4
4   4 0 5 2
5   5 0 5 5
6   6 1 0 1
7   7 0 3 0
8   8 1 2 4
9   9 0 5 5
10 10 0 2 5
11 11 0 4 3
12 12 0 1 4
13 13 1 1 4
14 14 0 1 3
15 15 0 2 4
16 16 0 5 2
17 17 1 2 0
18 18 0 4 1
19 19 1 5 2
20 20 0 2 1
```

A grouping (by Z and Q) that finds the X that maximizes Y, and returns both:

```
    DF =data.table(DF)
    DF[, list(Y=max(Y),X=X[which.max(Y)]), by=list(Z, Q)]
```

Result:

```
        DF[, list(Y=max(Y),X=X[which.max(Y)]), by=list(Z, Q)]
    Z Q Y  X
 1: 3 4 1  1
 2: 1 2 0  2
 3: 5 4 0  3
 4: 5 2 1 19
 5: 5 5 0  5
 6: 0 1 1  6
 7: 3 0 0  7
 8: 2 4 1  8
 9: 2 5 0 10
10: 4 3 0 11
11: 1 4 1 13
12: 1 3 0 14
13: 2 0 1 17
14: 4 1 0 18
15: 2 1 0 20
```

I want to do this purely using column numbers, because of the nature of my code.  Additionally, If there were another column, I would potentially want to group by that extra column.   And I would also want to potentially return another argmax in the first part.

Comment: It is better not to do with column numbers, but if you want, you may need to subset the names i.e. `setDT(DF)[, list(Y=max(Y),X=X[which.max(Y)]), by = c(names(DF)[3:4])]`

Comment: @akrun I need the X and Y part to be column name based as well, since the column names I use have to depend on the specification of many simulations I'm running. It's surprisingly hard to implement this ... –

Comment: You could simply save the original column names, rename them temporarily to a predetermined convention, and then write the original column names back after grouping. This can be done programmatically to allow any number of column names.

Comment: You mean like the below solution @Hack-R ?  The problem is that I want it to work for the X and Y as well.

Comment: @robertevansanders Not at all. That's not even similar. In fact I'm not sure what the logic is behind that answer.

Comment: Can you post then?

Comment: Could also just do `DF[, list(Y=max(.SD[[2]]),X=.SD[[1]][which.max(.SD[[2]])]), by=c(names(DF)[3:4])]` I guess. Also, please don't do `DF =data.table(DF)`. Just `setDT(DF)` or creating the data set using `DF <- data.table(...` in the first place should do

Comment: That would be a good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just pick off `names(DF)` with column numbers, combined with `eval(parse(...))`?

```
useColNums <- function(data, a, b) {
  n <- names(data) 
  y <- n[a[1]]
  x <- n[a[2]]
  groupby <- sprintf("list(%s)", paste(n[b], collapse=","))
  argmax <-  sprintf("list(%1$s=max(%1$s),%2$s=%2$s[which.max(%1$s)])", y, x)
  data[, eval(parse(text=argmax)), by=eval(parse(text=groupby))]  
}

x <- useColNums(DF, 2:1, 3:4)
y <- DF[, list(Y=max(Y),X=X[which.max(Y)]), by=list(Z, Q)]
identical(x, y)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. I've modified the answer so that `b` can be an arbitrary number of grouping columns.

Answer (score 1):

Did you find an answer that works for you?  Something like this is possible, but it is not pretty, which may mean it is hard to maintain:

```
DF[, list(Y=max(eval(as.symbol(colnames(DF)[2]))),
          X=eval(as.symbol(colnames(DF)[1]))[which.max(eval(as.symbol(colnames(DF)[2])))]),
          by=list(Z=eval(as.symbol(colnames(DF)[3])),
                  Q=eval(as.symbol(colnames(DF)[4])))]
```

Now you could put those `as.symbol(colnames())` into a function and make this easier to read:

```
cn <- function( dt, col ) { as.symbol(colnames(dt)[col]) }

DF[, list(Y=max(eval(cn(DF,2))),
          X=eval(cn(DF,1))[which.max(eval(cn(DF,2)))]),
          by=list(Z=eval(cn(DF,3)), Q=eval(cn(DF,4)))]
```

Does this solve that problem of grouping by column numbers for you?

Comment: It does not solve the problem because Y and X are still not column names

Comment: @robertevansanders I thought you just wanted to group by column numbers, which is why I only did those columns.  Using the same `eval(as.symbol(colnames()))` function, I replaced all of the column names as numbers in the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `grep` with your code:

```
> set.seed(007) 
> DF <- data.frame(X=1:20, Y=sample(c(0,1), 20, TRUE), Z=sample(0:5, 20, TRUE), Q =sample(0:5, 20, TRUE))
> DF = data.table(DF)
> coly <- na
> DF[, list(Y=max(Y),X=X[which.max(Y)]), by=c(col1 <- names(DF)[grep("Q", colnames(DF))], names(DF)[grep("Z", colnames(DF))])]
    Q Z Y  X
 1: 4 3 1  1
 2: 2 1 0  2
 3: 4 5 0  3
 4: 2 5 1 19
 5: 5 5 0  5
 6: 1 0 1  6
 7: 0 3 0  7
 8: 4 2 1  8
 9: 5 2 0 10
10: 3 4 0 11
11: 4 1 1 13
12: 3 1 0 14
13: 0 2 1 17
14: 1 4 0 18
15: 1 2 0 20
```

Comment: Want to have X and Y be col nums too :(